# Transfer Skype chat history to Fedora 17 from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, skype, fedora-17

I want to copy my Skype chat history from Windows 7 to Fedora 17. Is this possible?

I have found the Skype chat history in Windows 7 at the following:

```
Users/[username]/AppData/Roaming/Skype/[username]/main.db
```

But I have no idea where it is on Fedora 17.

Answer (score 0):

If they are different physical machines, you can just open skype on both computers at the same time. After some time the clients will sync their history.

Comment: no, i dont have two physical machines.

Comment: I don't think this works, (in terms of syncs) if you are signing into Skype with a MS (or messenger) account

Answer (score 0):

The location of the Skype folder is `~/.Skype/` (most probably `/home/fedorausername/.Skype`). Within that folder, there are subfolders for each username that logged into Skype on this particular computer.

Your file manager will probably hide the `~/.Skype` folder by default as it starts with a dot. You should be able to choose the option "Show hidden files" (wording may vary) or just use the terminal :-)